# How could I prove that L1 is undecidable?

Tags: computational-mathematics

The Problem:

```
Let L1 = {Kod(M) | M is a TM and when started with a blank input tape, M
eventually writes a 1 somewhere on the tape } Prove that L1 is undecidable.
```

I have the following 2 TMs whcih I have proved are undecidable to help me prove the current problem is undecidable. I want to use the reduction method to do so.

Key:

- TM : turing machine
- w : input string for the TM
- < kod(m) > : just means a binary encoding of a turing machine m being that TM.

  ```
  Ltm = { < kod(m), w > | m is a TM and m accepts w }

  Lh = { < kod(m), w > | m is a TM and m halts on w }
  ```